# VHDL behavioural vs structural performance

Tags: vhdl

I was wandering, in terms of "performance" if there's some kind of difference between vhdl structural and behavioural. I know that nowdays is more common to write behavioural instead of structural but since i'd like to have an understanding in terms of performance i have been thinking that maybe there's some difference...

Comment: It's always useful to look at the generated [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level) and compare.

Comment: You can do this for small system i guess... for big system you i don't think it make much sense to write both models and compare.

Comment: Usually it's your task to be productive and it's the compiler's task to understand your intentions. For this reason the behavioural code is usually preferred.

Comment: But is the structural synthesis different from a behavioural synthesis?

Comment: The result can be equal or it can be different, nobody can guarantee that.

Comment: What is performanc? Simulation speed, used registers, used LUTs, required ASIC gates, max frequency of the circuit?

Comment: Ok let's say in another way... i don't know if writing a VHDL code using behavioural or structural i could achieve more benefit in terms of any parameter that could be defined as "Performance". So i turn my question in the following for each behavioural model does exists a structural model such that the synthesis is exactly the same? what about the converse statement?

Comment: There is a structural model equivalent to any behavioral model. The converse is not necessary true, since it depends on the synthesis tool and not entirely on VHDL. Note that you can mix both approach in the same entity. Also, structural code running on several FPGA architecture is harder to get right. A generic structural code would not utilize a platform's special feature while a specific one would not run on another architecture.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hardware-related reason to prefer one form or the other.

It may be that one form leads to faster simulation than the other; I haven't seen any evidence for this in general, but then I haven't looked. It is true that after synthesis, the design is translated into a structural form, and post-synthesis simulation is slow, but this is due to the sheer size of the resulting structural version expressed as thousands of individual gates and their interconnections.

What matters more is the quality of synthesis results: It should be possible to write a design in both forms and have it synthesise to essentially the same hardware. And this seems to be generally true, in my experience.

Sometimes you will find synthesis tools have difficulty efficiently translating a construct (usually behavioural) but not as frequently as in the past.

---

What matters most (unless you are pushing the boundaries of speed or FPGA size) is clarity, leading to readability, reliability, efficiency, testability, maintainability and so on. If you can't understand it you can't see the inefficiencies or even test it properly.

Here, structural VHDL has a role to play at the top level : dividing a system into blocks like CPU, memory interface, FFT processor, UART, SPI  and so on. Sometimes hierarchically, so you might want to divide the memory interface into refresh logic, error correction, address multiplexing, and so on.

But most blocks - for example, tasks that a single state machine can handle, are clearest and simplest when expressed behaviourally.  So in a UART you might have two separate processes for TX and RX, while an SPI interface (which sends and receives on the same SPI clock) is probably best as a single behavioural process.

Comment: Since there's no specific reason to prefer a particular descritpion (in terms of hardware synthetized). Could the structural description affects somehow the compiling speed? (Assuming we have two equivalent hardware descriptions on behavioural and one structural).